# C code involving malloc for dynamic allocation of 2D array crashes after compiling

Tags: c, arrays, malloc, dynamic-arrays

I am trying to allocate the row dimension of an array (`a`) to the size of a user input value. Here is the code I have:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void FreeArray(int **arry, int N);

int main() {
    int **a;
    int **b;
    int N_a;
    int N;
    if (a != NULL) {
        FreeArray(a, N);
    }
    if (b != NULL) {
        FreeArray(b, N);
    }
    do {
        printf("Enter the size of the NxN array:\n");
        scanf("%d", &N);
        if (N < 2) {
            printf("Error, enter correct size.\n");
        }
    } while (N < 2);
    N_a = N;
    int errorInAlloc = 0;
    a = (int**)malloc(N_a * sizeof(int*));
    if (a != NULL) {
        errorInAlloc = 1;
    }
    return 0;
}

void FreeArray(int **arr, int N) {
    int i;
    if (arr == NULL)
        return;
    if (arr != NULL) {
        for (i = 0; i < N; i++) {
            if (arr[i] != NULL)
                free(arr[i]);
        }
        free(arr);
    }
}
```

The `FreeArray` function was provided to us, so I know it is correct. There is other code included in this, but I omitted is since it is just a menu. When I comment out `a = (int**) malloc(N_a * sizeof(int*));` the program compiles and runs without crashing or problems. When I include this line, the program compiles, but when I put a number greater than or equal to 2, it crashes. I have also tried `a = malloc(N_a * sizeof(int*));` and `a = (int**)malloc(N * sizeof(int*));` AND `a = malloc(N * sizeof(int*));` but all do the same thing.

I have been coding and running the program in Code::Blocks, but even when I compile it through the command prompt, it still crashes.

I have a hard time with arrays on a good day, so dynamically allocating arrays is so confusing to me, any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: In `if(a != NULL)` and `if(b != NULL)` you are testing *uninitialised variables*. Please turn on compiler warnings. If those variables happened to be not `NULL` then the `free`ing can crash the system, since the pointers are not to memory that was allocated by `malloc` or its cousins.

Comment: Note: Consider allocation simplification: `a = (int**)malloc(N_a * sizeof(int*));` --> `a = malloc(sizeof *a * N_a);`.  Easier to code, review and maintain.

Comment: @chux My personal preference is `a = malloc(N_a * sizeof *a)` because it mimics the order of the arguments in `calloc`.

Comment: @melpomene [That](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45446573/c-code-involving-malloc-for-dynamic-allocation-of-2d-array-crashes-after-compili?noredirect=1#comment77854406_45446573) does have that advantage.  I prefer starting with the `size_t` type as that insures the following product is calculated using `size_t` math: `sizeof *a * int_width * int_row)` that might overflow in another order.  Of course, make no product difference with only 2.

Comment: Why are you freeing the array before starting the program / allocating the array?

Comment: This is the obligatory, "Don't cast the return value of Malloc because it can conceal errors" comment.

Comment: `The FreeArray function was provided to us, so I know it is correct.` wrong assumption

Comment: Here is the obligatory link. See: [**Do I cast the result of malloc?**](http://stackoverflow.com/q/605845/995714)

Answer (score 2):

You have multiple errors in your program:

- variables `a` and `b` are uninitialized, comparing them to `NULL` is meaningless and passing them to `FreeArray` has undefined behavior.
- given how the `FreeArray` function is written, allocation must be performed in 2 steps:

  - allocate an array of of pointers, which you do.
  - initialize each element of the array with the address of an allocated array of `int`. which you don't.

Here is how a function `AllocArray` would be written:

```
int **AllocArray(int N) {
    int i;
    int **arr = calloc(sizeof(*arr), N);
    if (arr != NULL) {
        for (i = 0; i < N; i++) {
            arr[i] = calloc(sizeof(*arr[i]), N);
            if (arr[i] == NULL) {
                /* allocation failed: free allocated portion and return NULL */
                while (i-- > 0) {
                    free(arr[i]);
                }
                free(arr);
                return NULL;
            }
        }
    }
    return arr;
}
```

Note that the `FreeArray` function can be simplified this way:

```
void FreeArray(int **arr, int N) {
    int i;
    if (arr != NULL) {
        for (i = 0; i < N; i++) {
            free(arr[i]);
        }
        free(arr);
    }
}
```

It is OK to pass a null pointer to `free()`, and a single test on `arr` is sufficient.

Comment: @WeatherVane: good catch.  I used an explicit `return NULL;` that is provably less error prone ;-)

Comment: I notice, you usually go one better than recommendations! (mine was `arr = NULL;`

Comment: @WeatherVane: Your recommendation was good, and might help produce less code and comply with local coding rules (single exit point), and it was my intent to use this approach, but I forgot the necessary `arr = NULL;` statement and ruined the error detection. An explicit `return NULL;` is less error prone and more readable for beginners...

Comment: I prefer the early exit, it simplifies the code structure and the need for unnecessary `else` code blocks. Might depend on any clean-up required when the proper one-exit solution will be needed.

Comment: One calloc for the whole array. Easier (quicker) dereferencing, smaller overhead. In the complex matrix calculations every instruction counts

Comment: @PeterJ: I agree, but this simplification would require a change in the `FreeArray` function.  One might as well use a C99 2D array declared and allocated in one step with `int (*arr)[N] = calloc(sizeof(*arr), N);`

Comment: @chqrlie double dereferences terribly lower the quality of the optimisation. Even with single malloc and values of number of the rows and collums stored in the table - compilers do now absolutely amazing job. Just to see how it works (plain curiosity) : https://godbolt.org/g/V9ZjUL - and I am amazed. Another thing which amazes me is the ARM instruction set.

Comment: @PeterJ: amazing indeed. For consistency with `CreateArray()`, it seems the code should be: `inline int ArrayGet(int *p, int row, int column) {  return *(p + 2 + row * p[1] + column); }` and the same difference in `ArrayPut()`.

Comment: You right - but it is just the 5 min "sketch" - did not care about the consistency :)

Answer (score 1):

First problem is that you free an unallocated pointer:

```
 if(a != NULL)
 {
     FreeArray(a, N);
 }
```

You've never allocated memory for `a`, so when you try to access to a position of the vector, it generates a segmetation fault (same occurs with b). If you want to make sure that your pointer is `NULL`, just use `a = NULL;`. This will fix your problem.

There is another logical problem:

```
if(a != NULL)
{
    errorInAlloc = 1;
}
```

You return an error in allocation if a differs from NULL. You should return an error if `a` *is* `NULL` wich means that an error occurs in the memory allocation.

Answer (score 0):

Here's what gcc reported when your code was compiled with more warnings.

```
gcc -o xx xx.c -Wall -Wextra -pedantic -std=c99 -O2 -Wmissing-declarations -Wmissing-prototypes -Wconversion
xx.c: In function ‘main’:
xx.c:26:26: warning: conversion to ‘long unsigned int’ from ‘int’ may change the sign of the result [-Wsign-conversion]
a = (int **) malloc(N_a * sizeof(int *));
                      ^
xx.c:25:6: warning: variable ‘errorInAlloc’ set but not used [-Wunused-but-set-variable]
int errorInAlloc = 0;
  ^
xx.c:10:5: warning: ‘a’ is used uninitialized in this function [-Wuninitialized]
if (a != NULL) {
 ^
xx.c:13:5: warning: ‘b’ is used uninitialized in this function [-Wuninitialized]
if (b != NULL) {
 ^
xx.c:11:3: warning: ‘N’ may be used uninitialized in this function [-Wmaybe-uninitialized]
FreeArray(a, N);
^
```

The formatting is a little bit off. The point is crystal clear: Let your compiler help you locate errors.

Comment: The reason for "warning: `N` may be used uninitialized" is that the return value from `scanf` is not checked, to make sure that an input was properly scanned. *Always* check the result of user input functions, and if necessary, their value is in the expected valid range.